# Multiple concurrent sql dumps in mysql

Tags: mysql, concurrency, dump

My question is whether it is safe to perform multiple dumps at the same time in mysql, i.e. running:

```
mysql -u root -p database1 < database1.sql

mysql -u root -p database2 < database2.sql
```

on the same host and database server of course;

The databases will be empty when the process starts; (just created from cmd)

These are huge dumps if it matters, one file is 10G and the other 100G.

Comment: In most cases serial data load is more fast than parallel one.

Comment: The processes are likely to be heavy on I/O, so multiple parallel loads may saturate the I/O bandwidth.

Answer (score 2):

In general terms is safe as long as the databases are "independent". With this I mean each database has references only to itself.

For MySQL in particular VIEWs to missing tables are a problem.

Let me illustrate with an example:

```
create schema database1;
create table database1.mytable (id int);
create schema database2;
create view database2.myview as select * from database1.mytable;
```

We take separate dumps: database1.sql and database2.sql

If you try to restore them on a different server, we must pay attention to the restore order, let's say we are starting with empty schemas database1 and database2

This will work:

```
mysql -u root database1 < database1.sql
mysql -u root database2 < database2.sql
```

But this will fail:

```
mysql -u root -p database2 < database2.sql
mysql -u root -p database1 < database1.sql
```

Because the database2.myview references a table that does not exist.

**TLDR**: if you are running database restores in parallel and there are references between them you could get into trouble.